# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast string to int32 is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I only wrote a simple model in model.py, and when I ran it, it gave the following error.

2021-02-08 22:20:11.872409: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:641] Executor failed to create kernel. Unimplemented: Cast string to int32 is not supported
[[{{node embedding/Cast}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\trainer\task.py", line 55, in 
train_model(args)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\trainer\task.py", line 43, in train_model
validation_data=(eval_data, eval_labels))
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 780, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3289, in **call**
self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3222, in _make_callable
callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1489, in _make_callable_from_options
return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)
File "C:\Users\xiaoc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1446, in **init**
session._session, options_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast string to int32 is not supported
[[{{node embedding/Cast}}]]

What is the problem?  The requirement is to only make changes in model.py, not others. Thanks in advance!

Following are the three python files.

model.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Embedding,LSTM, Activation,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Model


def get_batch_size():  #size of training 8056  number of batches = 8056/128 

    return 128

def get_epochs():

    return 50

def solution(input_layer):
   
    max_len = 150
    max_words = 200
    # inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])
    layer = Embedding(max_words,output_dim = 64, input_length=max_len)(input_layer)
    # layer = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
    layer = tf.expand_dims(layer, axis=-1)
    layer = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(layer)
    layer = Dense(256,)(layer)
    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(5)(layer)
    # layer = Activation('softmax')(layer)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=layer)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
    

    return model
```

data.py

```
import csv

import numpy as np

label_map = {
    0: 'A',
    1: 'B',
    2: 'C',
    3: 'D',
    4: 'E',
}

label_map_inv = dict(map(reversed, label_map.items()))


def load_dataset(dataset_file):


    data = []
    labels = []
    with open(dataset_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
        next(data_reader)
        for lbl, desc in data_reader:
            data.append(desc)
            labels.append(label_map_inv[lbl])

    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

task.py

```
import os
import argparse
import logging

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras

import trainer.data as data
import trainer.model as model


def train_model(params):


    (train_data, train_labels) = data.load_dataset("data/train.csv")
    (eval_data, eval_labels) = data.load_dataset("data/eval.csv")

    input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(), name='input_text', dtype=tf.string)
    ml_model = model.solution(input_layer)

    if ml_model is None:
        print("No model found. You need to implement one in model.py")
    else:
        ml_model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
                     batch_size=model.get_batch_size(),
                     epochs=model.get_epochs(),
                     validation_data=(eval_data, eval_labels))
        _ = ml_model.evaluate(eval_data, eval_labels, verbose=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    args = parser.parse_args()
    tf_logger = logging.getLogger("tensorflow")
    tf_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = str(tf_logger.level // 10)

    train_model(args)
```

Comment: Looks like problem with train_data and train_labels. It should be something like this `train_data=tf.cast(train_data,tf.string)` and `train_labels=tf.cast(train_lables,tf.int32)`. Thanks!